# iOS: How i can achieve accordion (Drop Down) UI in my application as shown in pic?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, accordion

How can i do that in storyboard is there any library available which returns UIView to achieve that? Thanks in Advance.

[image]

Comment: Avijit for this, you need to set custom cell for Place/Gallery,Country and Contact No or else you can set only one custom cell for Place/Gallery,Country and Contact.

Comment: Show me the entire table view

Comment: This image from Web page. i want same ui in app

Comment: Did you try any other coding for this?

Comment: Yes i did it with Collapse Click library but it seems to not working on storyboard. can you suggest any library?

Comment: Let me try your requirement in my way.

Comment: what will next come after  place/gallery,Country,ContactNumber,From,...?

Comment: No Just that only. same view will reappear in each menu as collapse.

Comment: What are the textFields in your tableView?

Comment: place/gallery,Country,ContactNumber,From only.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96414/discussion-between-avijit-nagare-and-user3182143).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can achieve that by using `UITableViewController` - each cell would have 2 states: open and closed. When opened you'll insert a custom cell that has your design.

For more info you can look at this [sample code](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/DateCell/Introduction/Intro.html) provided by Apple.

Answer (score 0):

Finally i found very easy library for same which return custom UIView object. please check [This](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/accordionview) link for Accordionview. hope this help someone.